# Scale div width to content (within another div)

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the fiddle provided, I would like to have .content div width scale automatically to the fit the .product divs within it.

This is crucial as there will be varying amounts of products so a fixed width is not appropriate

http://jsfiddle.net/9GcM3/2/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
    <div class="product">
        <p>string</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <p>string</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <p>string</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <p>string</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <p>string</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <p>string</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <p>string</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <p>string</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
height:100px;
width:400px;
background:red;
padding:0 10px;
overflow-x: hidden;



}
    .content {
background:#eee;
height:70px;


    width: 2000px;

}
.product {
height:80px;
width:100px;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `width: auto;` on the `.content` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to find out how many products exist, then change the width of your content. Note, this will only work if all of your products have the same width, being 100px.

```
var products = $('.product').length;
var width = products * 100;
$('.content').css('width', width + 'px');
```

[**Here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9GcM3/3/)

You could even change the width of your `container` to make it fit nicely. You will need to remove the width on `content` though.

```
var products = $('.product').length;
var width = products * 100;
$('.container').css('width', width + 'px');
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9GcM3/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't set a width for it, and it'll change size depending on the width of the products?

Answer (score 0):

If it is necessary to set the width of the content, why not try

```
min-width: whatever;
```

That way, you can have a minimum width, but it will expand according to the width of the content.